# Localhost browses slowly when connected to internet

Tags: jquery, html, css

My localhost is browsing very slow when it is connected to internet. But when i disconnect my internet it works perfectly fine. Can anyone tell me what i have to do to solve this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean your localhost is 'browsing slowly'? Do you mean you're accessing a webpage on a server via localhost? And when you connect to that localhost page whilst also being connected to the internet, the localhost page runs slow?

Comment: I am using Xampp. So when i am reloading my webpage via localhost its runs slow.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: i am using chrome.

Comment: Try using URL `http://127.0.0.1/` instead (or https depending)

Comment: It works perfectly fine now. Thank you so much.